# В textarea при нажатии клавиши (пример, ctrl+b) вставить в текст тег <b>

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Как в textarea отследить что был нажат определенная клавиатура?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60908168/appending-text-in-textarea-with-hotkeys-and-javascript

Comment: Чащё всего это будет QWERTY клавиатура